# Como deletar as linhas duplicadas no banco de dados Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, delete

No meu banco tenho uma tabela que possui uma relação de (transportadora e especificações de resíduos) onde as transportadoras pode ter vários resíduos, verifiquei que os estão dados duplicados e estão representados dessa forma:

codigotrans_especificacoes_residuos | codigotransportadora | especificacoesresi

```
           1                    |             2        |           1        
           2                    |             2        |           5       
           3                    |             5        |           2        
           4                    |             5        |           5       
           5                    |             5        |           2       
           6                    |             8        |           1       
           7                    |             9        |           5        
           8                    |             9        |           5       
           9                    |            10        |           1        
           10                   |            10        |           3    
           11                   |            10        |           1    
           12                   |            10        |           1    
           13                   |            10        |           5
```

Fiz uma consulta para me dizer a quantidade linha duplicadas e deu certo porém com duvidas para retirar esses dados duplicados do banco.

```
SELECT codigotransportadora,especificacoesresi, count(*) FROM transportadorasespecificacoesresiduos
WHERE
codigotransportadora <> 0
AND especificacoesresi<> 0
GROUP BY codigotransportadora,especificacoesresi
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
 ORDER BY codigotransportadora)
```

Resultado da consulta :

codigotransportadora | especificacoesresi| count

```
     5           |             2     |      2        
     9           |             5     |      2      
     10          |             1     |      3
```

Estou quebrando a cabeça tentando criar um Script para Deletar esses duplicados...

Comment: coloca no http://sqlfiddle.com/ se possível, e qual a condição pra deletear ? `5|2` tem o `codigotrans_especificacoes_residuos` como 3 e 5, qual deles apaga ?

Comment: no resulta da consulta mostra a quantidade de duplicado, to procurando uma forma de excluir e deixar apenas um registro.

Comment: eu sei, mas a coluna `codigotrans_especificacoes_residuos` não está duplicada, qual deles será deletado ?

Comment: tanto faz não vai impactar na minha aplicação, porem só precisa ter um registro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Selecione os registros duplicados em uma tabela temporária

```
with duplicadas as 
(SELECT 
codigotransportadora,
especificacoesresiduos, 
count(*) FROM tabela
GROUP BY codigotransportadora,especificacoesresiduos
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY codigotransportadora)
```

> Delete da tabela onde existir na tabela temporária e mantenha ao menos um (neste caso o maior valor de `codigotrans_especificacoes_residuos`):

```
delete from tabela 
where exists (select 1 
              from duplicadas 
              where duplicadas.codigotransportadora = tabela.codigotransportadora 
              and duplicadas.especificacoesresiduos = tabela.especificacoesresiduos)
and tabela.codigotrans_especificacoes_residuos <> (select 
                                                   max(t.codigotrans_especificacoes_residuos) 
                                                   from tabela t
                                                   where t.codigotransportadora = tabela.codigotransportadora
                                                   and t.especificacoesresiduos = tabela.especificacoesresiduos);
```

Veja no SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/560712/5

**Outra opção (Usando Window functions - Rank)**

> Faça o rank em uma tabela temporária:

```
with rank as (
select
codigotrans_especificacoes_residuos,
especificacoesresiduos,
codigotransportadora,
rank() over (Partition by especificacoesresiduos,codigotransportadora order by codigotrans_especificacoes_residuos desc) as i
from tabela)
```

> Delete onde o rank for maior que 1:

```
delete from tabela 
where exists (select 1 from rank 
              where rank.codigotrans_especificacoes_residuos = tabela.codigotrans_especificacoes_residuos
              and rank.especificacoesresiduos = tabela.especificacoesresiduos
              and rank.codigotransportadora = tabela.codigotransportadora
              and rank.i > 1);
```

Obs: O código da tabela temporária (With) tem que ser executado no mesmo comando que o delete.

Veja no SQLFiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/560712/10

Comment: Nossa mano, deu certo a opção usando "Outra opção (Usando Window functions - Rank)" fiquei impressionado, estou muito grato a ajuda.

Comment: você tem que marcar como resposta para sua pergunta, se tiver dificuldades pode fazer  o [tour] da comunidade pra saber como funciona =]

Comment: beleza, pronto.

Answer (score 0):

Uma possibilidade é você utilizar a cláusula DISTINCT ON para criar uma tabela auxiliar sem duplicatas e depois substituir a tabela original pela auxiliar.

```
CREATE TABLE ter AS SELECT DISTINCT ON(codigotransportadora, especificacoesresi), *  FROM transportadorasespecificacoesresiduos;
```